# ngModel not working along with value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have this update user profile page which on load the already existed customer_name is to be displayed and can be updated by customer.
If I remove ngModel the value is being displayed but when I add ngModel, it is not working.

This is my code. Can anybody tell what is my mistake.

```
   <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="saveEntry()">
        <ion-list *ngFor="let user of foundUser">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" name="customer_name" formControlName="customer_name" value="{{user.name.last}}" [(ngModel)]="data.customer_name"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </form>
```

Comment: Use    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.customer_name.name.last"></ion-input>

Comment: @Ajay value is coming from *ngFor = let user...

Comment: You want to show customer name in form? is that the purpose you are using ngModel?

Comment: i have to update my form which contains already existed value

Comment: @nas use <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name.last"></ion-input>. What does data contain and how it is different from user?

Comment: @nas Kindly check my answer.

Comment: @Ajay ngModel == user.name.last is giving me result. but on form submit how to get this data.

Comment: @nas all changes made using ngModel is going to remain in user object. You can parse the foundUser array for fetching the updated value. I hope it helps.

Comment: First of all, decide to use template driven form **or** reactive form, it's not good idea to mix them both, since you are now having 2 different bindings (ngModel and formControlName) which makes no sense and can cause unexpected issues.

Comment: @Alex, thank you for suggetion. Can you provide me example or tutorial that I can follow.

Comment: well the official docs are quite good: https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms and https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: anyway, don't use `value` to set value in either of the type of form you choose. If you use template driven, set value to ngModel. If you use reactive form, set the value to the formcontrol.

Comment: If you want help with your current problem, please create a minimal, verifiable example showcasing the issue. Best would be to provide a stackblitz or plunker. The code we are seing now is not enough code to reproduce the issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need value when you are using ngModel

```
<ion-input type="text" name="customer_name" formControlName="customer_name" [(ngModel)]="data.customer_name"></ion-input>
```

Comment: But I need to show the value of customer name. Its the update form page

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't assign the value for `data.customer_name` object on init. 
If you want to use `data.customer_name` as a value of `user.name.last` then try this below way

```
<ion-input type="text" name="customer_name" formControlName="customer_name" 
 value="{{data.customer_name = user.name.last}}" [(ngModel)]
 ="data.customer_name"></ion-input>
```

I don't know why you are using `data.customer_name` instead of `user.name.last`. Because if you want two way data binding, the you can use `user.name.last` in ng-model directly without using `value` and a new object as `data.customer_name`

Comment: I am getting this error:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 22 in [{{data.customer_name = user.name.last}}] in ng:///AppModule/ProfilePage.html@50:97 (">

                    <ion-input type="text" name="customer_name" formControlName="customer_name"  [ERROR ->]value="{{data.customer_name = user.name.last}}" [(ngModel)]="data.customer_name"></ion-input>

Comment: go and use `init` instead of `value`

Comment: @nas did you initialize your model object?